# My floating value doesn't match my value in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm trying to interface a board with a raspberry.
I have to read/write value to the board via modbus, but I can't write floating point value like the board.

I'm using C, and Eclipse debug perspective to see the variable's value directly.
The board send me 0x46C35000 which should value 25'000 Dec but eclipse shows me 1.18720512e+009...

When I try on this website http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_float.html?hexadecimal=46C35000 I obtain 25,000.

What's the problem?

For testing purposes I'm using this:

```
int main(){
    
    while(1){ // To view easily the value in the debug perspective 
        float test = 0x46C35000;
        printf("%f\n",test);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `0x46C35000` is 1187205120, not 25'000. Why do you expect 25'000?

Comment: Because for the board it is 25'000... It's a constructor value for a gauge… If can't view variable as the board i wonder how i will be able to send it the right new value.

Comment: Regarding your `while loop` and your comment next to it: Don’t do this. Instead, configure your IDE/editor properly so that the program output is still shown after the program terminates in debug mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
float test = 0x46C35000;
```

You're setting the **value** to 0x46C35000 (decimal 1187205120), not the **representation**.

You can do what you want as follows:

```
union {
    uint32_t i;
    float f;
} u = { 0x46C35000 };

printf("f=%f\n", u.f);
```

This safely allows an unsigned 32-bit value to be interpreted as a `float`.

Comment: So this "structure" allow me to use a Hex value, but showing as a float in printf ?
It takes twice the amount of memory or is there a magical trick I don't see here ?

Comment: @Arnaud Please read about how a `union` works in C: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm

Comment: @Arnaud Each member of a `union` starts at the same memory address, so the size of the `union` is the size of the largest member.  It allows you to reinterpret a variable of one type as another.

Comment: @Arnaud: There are not hexadecimal values or decimal values. A value is a number, and abstract mathematical entity. There are hexadecimal or decimal numerals, in which we interpret the digits in a base to figure out which number they represent. Although C has some association between numerals and types (whether an integer is in hexadecimal may influence whether it is unsigned, and having a period marks it as floating-point), assigning a value to a `float` just sets its value to that value; it is not an instruction to set the bits of the `float` to the apparent bits of a hexadecimal numeral.

Comment: @dbush: The size of a union is at least as large as its largest member. It may be larger and must be if a smaller member’s alignment requirement forces padding.

Comment: I would like to put multiple union in a struct, how should i do it ? 
They should be different from each other. I've tried with the union but it's like my différents union are just the same…

Comment: @Arnaud you should post that as a new question.  Be sure to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

You’re confusing logical value and internal representation. Your assignments sets the *value*, which is thereafter 0x46C35000, i.e. 1187205120.

To set the internal representation of the floating point number you need to make a few assumptions about how floating point numbers are represented in memory. The assumptions on the website you’re using (IEEE 754, 32 bit) are fair on a general purpose computer though.

To change the internal representation, use [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) to copy the raw bytes into the float:

```
// Ensure our assumptions are correct:

#if !defined(__STDC_IEC_559__) && !defined(__GCC_IEC_559)
#    error Floating points might not be in IEEE 754/IEC 559 format!
#endif

_Static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t), "Floats are not 32 bit numbers");
```

```
float f;
uint32_t rep = 0x46C35000;
memcpy(&f, &rep, sizeof f);
printf("%f\n", f);
```

Output: `25000.000000`.

(This requires the header `stdint.h` for `uint32_t`, and `string.h` for `memcpy`.)

Comment: I didn't knew that, I thought the type "float" fixed the representation, and therefore it should be the same in the printf… 
So you're telling me i have to do additional steps to have it under a float form ?

Comment: @Arnaud `printf` prints the *value*, not the *internal representation* of the variable.

Comment: A more pedantic assertion would be `sizeof(float)*CHAR_BIT == 32` or perhaps a cleaner direct test would be `sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)`

Comment: @chux I knew that somebody would make this observation but I fear that considering the case of `CHAR_BIT` ≠ 8 would confuse OP even more. That said, your second test is indeed cleaner.

Comment: It may be worth noting that (language lawyer issues apart) the compilers are allowed to optimize away the call to `memcpy`: https://godbolt.org/z/yXS-cN

Comment: @Bob__ Oh it better optimise it away, I’d expect that from any competent compiler. What I honestly find more interesting in the link you posted is that both clang and GCC do tail-call elimination for `printf`. I thought varargs would inhibit this.

Answer (score 3):

The constant `0x46C35000` being assigned to a `float` will implicitly convert the `int` value `1187205120` into a `float`, rather than directly overlay the bits into the IEEE-754 floating point format.

I normally use a `union` for this sort of thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
    float f;
    uint32_t i;
} FU;

int main()
{
    FU foo;

    foo.f = 25000.0;
    printf("%.8X\n", foo.i);

    foo.i = 0x46C35000;
    printf("%f\n", foo.f);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
46C35000
25000.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can understand how data are represented in memory when you access them through their address:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float f25000; // totally unused, has exactly same size as `int'
    int i = 0x46C35000; // put binary value of 0x46C35000 into `int' (4 bytes representation of integer)
    float *faddr; // pointer (address) to float
    faddr = (float*)&i; // put address of `i' into `faddr' so `faddr' points to `i' in memory

    printf("f=%f\n", *faddr); // print value pointed bu `faddr'

    return 0;
}
```

and the result:

```
$ gcc -of25000 f25000.c; ./f25000
f=25000.000000
```

What it does is:
put `0x46C35000` into int `i`

copy address of `i` into `faddr`, which is also address that points data in memory, in this case of `float` type

print value pointed by `faddr`; treat it as `float` type

you get your `25000.0`.